# Getting different values for LastTradePriceOnly in Yahoo Finance API after hours

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I noticed a strange behavior with the Yahoo Finance API quotes. After hours, when the `LastTradePriceOnly` should be constant, I get toggling values when I reissue the request.
i.e. I get 4.27 for the first 2 trials, then I get 4.20 on the next and then 4.27 again. It toggles back and forth between those two values (4.27 being the 'correct' one that also shows on the web page).

This applies to all Tickers, not just one and since this is a significant difference, it really renders the API more or less useless. I tried to google this and couldn't find anyone else complaining. I'm not posting any code since I can see the 2 JSONs being plain different when I refresh the browser with the same URL request, so it's clearly an issue on the Yahoo side.

btw. , it's weird that they name this `LastTradePriceOnly`, but that's the only metric that seems to reflect the correct value (also during the trading day)